# menustrip menu dropdown items names appear blank in msgbox

Tags: vb.net

I have on my form load to add items to a menu as a dropdown item.

from within the same sub I try to output the menustrip dropdown items in a msgbox but I get a blank response for all my items.

```
Private Sub PopulateLoadChildMenu()
    msItemLoad.DropDownItems.Clear()
    Dim fi As FileInfo
    If Directory.GetFiles(_playlistpath).Length > 1 Then
        msItemLoad.Enabled = True
    End If

    For Each fi In _files
        msItemLoad.DropDownItems.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_playlistpath & fi.Name))
    Next

    For Each MyMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem In msItemLoad.DropDownItems
        txbList.Text = txbList.Text & ", " & MyMenuItem.Tag
    Next

End Sub
```

I use it in a Sub like this

```
Private Sub FormLoad(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim fi As FileInfo
    msItemLoad.Enabled = False

   If Directory.GetFiles(_playlistpath).Length = 1 Then
        For Each fi In _files
            LoadPlaylist(_playlistpath & fi.Name)
        Next
    End If

   PopulateLoadChildMenu()

End Sub
```

Comment: Are they showing up in your Menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code you are using the `Tag` Property(*if your are not explicitly setting data there you will be adding nothing to your TextBox*):

```
txbList.Text = txbList.Text & ", " & MyMenuItem.Tag
```

Are you meaning to be using the `Text` Property

```
txbList.Text = txbList.Text & ", " & MyMenuItem.Text
```

Comment: perfect! i'm sorry the Text attribute completely went past me.